# String input in MIPS omits the first four characters that are inputted

Tags: string, assembly, mips, user-input

```
.data
EntryReq:
    .asciiz "Please enter an 8 digit hexadecimal MIPS instruction: \n"
InputLongError:
    .asciiz "\nYour input was too long, make sure it is 8 digits. "
InputShortError:
    .asciiz "\nYour input was too short, make sure it is 8 digits. "
CharInvalidError:
    .asciiz "\nYour input contains an invalid character. "
ValidChars:
    .asciiz "0123456789abcdef\n\b\0"

.align 4
input:
    .space 20

.text

main:
    #Print input request
    la $a0, EntryReq #loads input into arg. reg.
    li $v0, 4 #op code for print string
    syscall

    #take input for input (stored)
    li $v0, 8 #op code for take user input
    la $a0, input #provide address for syscall
        li $a1, 20 # tell syscall the byte space required for the string
    syscall

    #move to input(stored)
    sw $v0, input #move inputted into from $v0 to input(stored)

    #check validity of input
    la $a0, input #load address of input to arg. reg. for method call
    la $a1, ValidChars #load address of string of valid chars
    jal verifyInput #call the verifyInput method which does as expected 

    #test if string length count works
    addi $a0, $v0, 0 #load from $v0 to arg. reg.
    li $v0, 1 #op code for print int
    syscall

terminate:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

verifyInput:
    li $v0, -1 #start length count at 0
verifyLoop:
    lb $t0, ($a0) #load current 
    li $a2, 0 #loop for char check, loops up to length of validChar string
    la $a1, ValidChars
    j checkChar
charVerified: #ignore this, is entry point back into verifyLoop for checkChar
    addi $a0, $a0, 1 #increment 
    addi $v0, $v0, 1
    bgt $v0, 8, printTooLongError #if result bigger than 8, error
    bne $t0, 10, verifyLoop #10 is string end, so check if string is end
    blt $v0, 8, printTooShortError #if result less than 8, error
    jr $ra #if here string input was confirmed okay

checkChar: # loops through valid chars for each char in $a0                 | Valid Chars: 0123456789abcdef\n |
    lb $t1, ($a1) #loads in byte from char string
    addi $a1, $a1, 1 #increment address, for the next char
    addi $a2, $a2, 1 #increment until length of valid char string is reached
    beq $t0, $t1, charVerified
    bne $a2, 19, checkChar #if length of valid chars changes, change second argument here
    j charNotValidError
charNotValidError:
    la $a0, CharInvalidError #loads input into arg. reg.
    li $v0, 4 #op code for print string
    syscall
    j terminate
printTooLongError:
    la $a0, InputLongError #loads input into arg. reg.
    li $v0, 4 #op code for print string
    syscall
    j terminate
printTooShortError:
    la $a0, InputShortError #loads input into arg. reg.
    li $v0, 4 #op code for print string
    syscall
    j terminate
```

The general gist of this code is for the user to input an 8 digit hexadecimal string, and then the program checks whether it is a valid hexadecimal string (i.e. includes only 0-9 and a-f). However, whenever I run it, the string that I input is missing the first four characters. So if I place invalid characters in the first four digits, like wwww1abc, then the code runs fine, which it shouldn't. But if I do 1abcwwww, it outputs an invalid character error, which it should. I'm genuinely confused as to why this is the case, nor have I seen anyone else experience this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
#move to input(stored)
sw $v0, input #move inputted into from $v0 to input(stored)
```

Unlike `read integer` syscall, `read string` puts the result in the input buffer, in your case `input`. So you don't need to read out the value in `$v0` and by storing it in `input` you're overwriting the first 4 bytes of the buffer with the value of `$v0`, which is still `0x00000008`, which conveniently is the same as the string "\b\0\0\0" for little endian machines, all of which are in your validity list. Removing that line should fix your program (though I didn't look over all the rest of the code for errors).